# Why no boundary in Content-Type: RFC 7233 Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1) : "Range Requests"

Tags: range, content-type, rfc, http-1.1

How can I get information about `boundary=THIS_STRING_SEPARATES` in my curl response?
In the curl request below I was able to get the following response:

```
curl http://www.example.com -i -H "Range: bytes=0-50, 100-150"
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Age: 257454
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 13 Feb 2021 08:40:42 GMT
Etag: "3147526947+ident"
Expires: Sat, 20 Feb 2021 08:40:42 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT
Server: ECS (sjc/16C5)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: HIT
Content-Length: 312


--3d6b6a416f9b5
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Range: bytes 0-50/1256

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Do
--3d6b6a416f9b5
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Range: bytes 100-150/1256

eta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; c
--3d6b6a416f9b5--
```

According to rfc 7233 4.1, it says:

> If multiple parts are being transferred, the server generating the
> 206 response MUST generate a "multipart/byteranges" payload, as
> defined in Appendix A, and a Content-Type header field containing the
> multipart/byteranges media type and its required boundary parameter.

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Wed, 15 Nov 1995 06:25:24 GMT 
Last-Modified: Wed, 15 Nov 1995 04:58:08 GMT 
Content-Length: 1741
Content-Type: multipart/byteranges; boundary=THIS_STRING_SEPARATES
--THIS_STRING_SEPARATES 
Content-Type: application/pdf 
Content-Range: bytes 500-999/8000
...the first range... 
--THIS_STRING_SEPARATES 
Content-Type: application/pdf 
Content-Range: bytes 7000-7999/8000
...the second range 
--THIS_STRING_SEPARATES--
```

```
Content-Type: multipart/byteranges; boundary=THIS_STRING_SEPARATES
```

There is no specification in the spec that it can be created without including the following header `boundary=THIS_STRING_SEPARATES` in any part.

But the response to my curl response is consistent with `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8.`
How can I get information about `boundary=THIS_STRING_SEPARATES` in my curl response? and Why?

Thank you.

Comment: This looks like a non-conforming implementation, especially with the content-length that doesn't seem to belong there. The content-length seems to apply to the entire response body, that _contains_, but isn't, a chunked response. What cache server is this?

Comment: That is an example server specified in mdn: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests's Multipart ranges

Comment: mdn got ```Content-Type: multipart/byteranges; boundary=3d6b6a416f9b5``` as an example of ```curl http://www.example.com -i -H "Range: bytes=0-50, 100-150"```, but I got a response to curl like above

Comment: So you copy-pasted together a non-working example? What exactly is your question? If the server properly supports range requests, the content-type response header will contain the boundary.

Comment: No, I made a curl request for an example that stated it works fine in mdn, and my response didn't include the boundary. What I'm asking is, can range work even though boundary isn't part of the content-type?

Comment: And there is nothing wrong with the content-length. This is the correct value. Actually the web server can change depending on the time requested. However, if the boundary value is not specified due to some rule applied later, I am asking which specification to look at. For reference, the response http version is 1.1.

Comment: Thanks for responding. ```If the server properly supports range requests, the content-type response header will contain the boundary.``` I agree with this opinion. 
To be more specific: the question is, can I change it to ```must``` instead of ```will``` in your answer? The reason I ask this question is that it is an example of mdn, one of the sites that is considered official, not just an example. If such a response came out, there would be a reason.

Comment: I don't know which response you're talking about. I see a 206 with a content-type with a boundary on MDN.

Comment: Yes. In the MDN example, the response to the URL contains boundary. But now, when I make a request to the same web server URL, the response to the above question comes. It was the web server URL selected by the official homepage at the moment, so that there is a main reason for that, even if another response comes. Of course, the web server is wrong if it is according to the specifications, but there may be changes after that that I do not know. I asked a question to be sure.

Comment: Ah, so you literally issued a request to example.com. I'd say that that server does not respond confirming to specs, but I haven't got the time to dive into said specs right now. Look at them to see whether a 206 MUST be accompanied with a content-type response header with a boundary. You seem to have done so, and the specs seem to confirm my suspicions.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Have a nice day. Nevertheless, I am not sure in the later specs, It is stated that rfc 7233 4.1 must be included. Obviously, it doesn't seem like a major issue as you don't know exactly. (you have far more experience than me, most of them are proof that they were properly included.). I'll find a little more. Thank you.